# Getting data from multiple join in a single row

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am having five tables having relations like

```
Rooms
> Id | Hotel_ID | Room_Type
Room Price
> Id | Room_Id | Price | Start_Date
Room Image
> Id | Room_Id | Image
Room Amenity
> Id | Room_Id | Amenity
Amenity
> id | Amenity
```

in this case ROOM table can have multiple rooms for a hotel and For Every room it can have multiple  Room Price , Room Image , Amenity

i want to find all rooms of a hotel having all prices  , images and amenity in a single row.

I am using  this query which is producing ambiguous result i.e. multiple rows for a single row.

```sql
SELECT hr.*, 
       group_concat(Distinct  ra.amenity_id) AS amenity_id,
       group_concat( Distinct  a.amenity) AS amenity,
       group_concat(Distinct  g.image) AS image,
       group_concat(Distinct rp.start_date) As Start_date
FROM hotel_rooms AS hr
LEFT JOIN hotel_room_amenity AS ra ON ra.room_id = hr.id
LEFT JOIN amenities AS a ON ra.amenity_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN hotel_room_gallery AS g ON hr.id = g.hotel_room_id
LEFT JOIN hotel_room_price AS rp ON hr.id = rp.room_id
WHERE hr.hotel_id = '24'
group by hr.id
```

Comment: Is there a missing `group_concat` before `(distinct g.image)`?

Comment: There's no `start_date` column in the `Room Price` table.

Comment: I don't think you'd be needing `group_concat(Distinct  ra.amenity_id) AS amenity_id` in your result.

Comment: but i want to merge all related data with no repetation